# Dropbox vulnerability details

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, cloud-computing

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) (the online cloud storage provider) was recently in the news for some security and privacy vulnerabilities. What was the problem, and what has been done to resolve it?

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a great question for IT Security.  You could have learned the answer by simply using Google.  If you can't take the time to do a simple Google search before posting your question, you are being disrespectful to others on this site: I think we ought to be able to expect at a minimum that you will spend 5 minutes with Google before expecting others to volunteer their time to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was been at least five issues reported over the past few months

1. Problem with [authentication](http://dereknewton.com/2011/04/dropbox-authentication-static-host-ids/), ie  if you could access a hard disc that contained a dropbox folder you would have continuous access to their dropbox data
2. Data stored in dropbox is accessible by [dropbox employees](http://www.bnet.com/blog/technology-business/-8220at-dropbox-even-we-cant-see-your-dat-8211-er-nevermind-8221-update/10077)
3. A recent code update meant that any dropbox account could be accessed with just the users [email address](http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=821) for a short period of time.
4. The Terms of service were recently updated to give Dropbox much wider privileges to your [data](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/11/07/02/0515218/Dropbox-TOS-Includes-Broad-Copyright-License)
5. You can detect if another user has uploaded a file to dropbox by monitoring the amount of time it takes to upload the [file](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=13223)

Answer (score 3):

I know of two in the last little while.  Wired did a reasonably good job explaining both: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/06/dropbox/ and http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/05/dropbox-ftc/.

Comment: Down-voted for no actual content in answer.

Comment: @Iszi Really? Come on... It was a googleable answer that they could have found themself.

Comment: @SteveS - exactly, we shouldnt encourage googlebait. I didnt downvote you, but I strongly considered closing the question... As I discussed in [chat].

Answer (score 2):

Basically what it gets at is the same thing as always, you need to encrypt data before giving it to a third party.  The other security problem is you can masquerade as the properly authenticated user for an account.
[Schneier dropbox article](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/05/dropbox_securit.html)